# Reading data from excel spreadsheet with the for loop. Can't get the second value in column

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I cannot get the second value from the excel spreadsheet to insert in the password field, it seems that my for loop is wrong. The password should be inserted from the Excel sheet into the field. Can somebody please give me a solution on this?

```
        //My code
        using OfficeOpenXml;
        using OpenQA.Selenium;
        using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
        using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
        using System;
        using System.IO;
        
        namespace LoginSuperUser_New
        {
            public class LoginSuperuser
            {
                static void Main (String[] args)
                { 
                    //Open Chrome Driver
                    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\27828\source\repos\");
                    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;
                    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\DATA\UserLoginData.xlsx");
                    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
                    {
                        //get the first worksheet in the workbook
                        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
                        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
                        int row = 2;
                        int col = 1;
        
                        //Open Environment
                        object cellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl((string)cellValue);
                        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        
                        for (col = 2; col <= colCount; col++)
                        {
                            for (row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
                            {
        
                                //Enter the Username
                                IWebElement UserName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Input_Email"));
                                object UserN = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
                                UserName.SendKeys((string)UserN);
                                                       
                                col = col + 1;
//This code cannot get the second value from the excel spreadsheet
                                //Enter the Password
                                IWebElement PassWOrd = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Input_Password"));
                                object PasSWord = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
                                PassWOrd.SendKeys((string)PasSWord);
                                
                                
                    }
                     
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what is not working however, the line... `col = col + 1;` ... looks very suspicious. It would appear for each row, `col` is incremented by 1, this is going to mess up the outer `for` loop where its index is `col`

Comment: Yes, I have noticed.  The problem is when I debug through the code it enters the Username and enter the Username again in the password, it doesn't step to the next Password column to get the correct data.  I have for instance 3 columns and 5 rows with the same URL, and different Usernames and Passwords.

Comment: Somewhere between this code there must be code that force it to the Password column to be entered in the Password field.

Comment: IWebElement UserName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Input_Email"));
                        object UserN = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
                        UserName.SendKeys((string)UserN);
                       
                        //Enter the Password
                        IWebElement PassWOrd = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Input_Password"));
                        object PasSWord = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
                        PassWOrd.SendKeys((string)PasSWord);

Comment: Still not understanding what you are trying to do. Instead of adding 1 to `col` and breaking the outer loop, you could try changing the line… `object PasSWord = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;` … to … `object PasSWord = worksheet.Cells[row, col + 1].Text;` … however I am betting this is just going to create a different problem. What columns are wanting to get in the 5 rows? If you want to get two values from two different columns in each row, then use only one loop through the rows. With each iteration, grab the two values from the columns you want.

Comment: I want to get the Username and Password which is 2 columns with 5 rows

Comment: So in the Excel there are 3 columns which contains Url  Username  Password.  I catch the Url once for all 5 rows but the Username and Passwords differs for each row for the login

Comment: As I stated previously, it looks like the outer loop is unnecessary. Just loop through the rows and get the cells from `..Cells[row, index of username column]`  …and … `..Cells[row, index of password column]`